# changing the protocol for client to server

Tags: windows, tcp, network-programming, udp, sctp

I have to test the value from client to server using different protocols (Tcp , UDP , Sctp).
Please guide how it can be possible. Is there any way in windows to change the protocol or is there anyway to find it by using software like packet tracer .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question is not entirely clear, it sounds as though your interested in seeing the information sent between the client and the server when each of those protocols is used.

Windows does not provide a built in utility to view packet data but it can be viewed using a packet analyser such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

In order to see the values sent by each protocol you must run a client for each of the protocols and use it to connect to the server for that protocol. If you don't have a server to connect to, you may need to run one on your local machine.

You can narrow down the data captured to just the protocol you're interested in using a filter in Wireshark If you don't know the protocol being used, you can filter by the port number used for that connection which can be established using the `netstat` command.

You may need to use `netstat -b` to show you which programs are using which ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to generate packets using different protocols then the tool like netcat can also help. It supports TCP and UDP and has been ported to [windows](http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139) .